# Oozie coordinator start date set to actual date

Tags: date, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is there a way to set start date of coordinator to actual date? Everytime I want to run my coordinator I have to manually set start date of the coordinator job:

```
<coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="60" start="2014-11-27T05:00Z" end="2015-01-01T06:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```

I want to use some kind of varaible that will be set this date for my to date that I run the coordinator:

```
<coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="60" start="${actualTime}" end="2015-01-01T06:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```

How can I set the actualTime do the sysdate?
I tried use EL function timestamp() but it does not works or maybe I use it wrong.
Maybe is there a way to set in the .properties file any variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to pass the sysdate from shell script to the coordinator job thru command line.

See if the answer to a similar question works for you : [Oozie coordinator with sysdate as start time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262938/oozie-coordinator-with-sysdate-as-start-time/27330462#27330462)

Comment: Thank You Paul H., it could works for me but I wonder that there is a way to keep this idea but to not change form of command to run oozie job? I mean that I don't want to pass -D parameter?

Comment: Is there a way to provide this solution by variable in .properties file?

Comment: Oozie is using EL(similar JSP's) internally to interpolate expressions. It's pretty much limited to some built-in objects and operations. Something like a java expression "new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'").format(new Date())" will not work unfortunately.