# Oozie coordinator with sysdate as start time

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to run oozie coordinator with start time as sysdate. How do I do that?
is it possible to put sysdate as start date  ? Will it catch up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make coorodinator's "start" refer to a variable - startTime, then overwrite its value with sysdate from command line, such as:

```
 oozie job -run -config ./coord.properties -DstartTime=`date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:00Z"`
```

adjust the time format if you are not using UTC time zone in your system.

sample coordinator job xml:

```
<coordinator-app name="my-coord"                               
    frequency="${frequency}" start="${startTime}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" 
    xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">                                    
    <action>                                                              
            <workflow> ...
```

coordinator attribute file coord.properties:

```
...
startTime=2014-05-19T22:00Z 
end=2015-01-19T22:08Z   
frequency=60 ...
```